# Using Bootstrap on IIS

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to test bootstrap. Simple HTML code works well on my computer, yet when I put it on the web site, it does not work with IE9 (works well on chrome). Is there any special IIS settings or is there a problem with my IE? If there is a problem with my IE why does it work correctly when the HTML page is run from my computer?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
</head><body>
<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn">Left</button>
<button class="btn">Middle</button>
<button class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find an answer directly but I found a bunch of similar questions for ASP websites hosted on IIS. They all talked about something being wrong with the links to the CSS and that you either need to remove all the minified (.min) files or just directly link to them.

I removed all of the .min files because I do not use them and so far everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of resources, you can use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) addon to help you with lost references.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn">Left</button>
<button class="btn">Middle</button>
<button class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```